# Do/Should I use JOIN? (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Basically, I want to join 2 different tables, but I am not sure how to join some fields without a primary key.

This is an example of my dataset:

---

**Table 1**

| Name | Team | Rol | Client | Service | Time spent (h) | Client ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Marketing | Analyst | Levis | Email | 5 | 001 |
| Max | Marketing | Manager | Levis | Paid Media | 7 | 001 |
| Damian | Marketing | Analyst | Timberland | Paid Media | 7 | 004 |

**Table 2**

| Name | Team | Rol | Client | Service | Time spent (h) | Client ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Noah | Business | Analyst | Levis | Operations | 8 | 001 |
| Alex | Business | KAM | Levis | Consultancy | 6 | 001 |
| Mary | Business | KAM | Vans | Consultancy | 6 | 002 |

---

As you can see, in both tables I have 2 different people who worked on different clients: Mary and Damian. This is a concise example of my dataset, but I have a lot of people who are in the same situation as Mary and Damian.

Currently, I am using the next query within BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
    M.Client_ID,
    M.Client,
    SUM(C.Time_spent_h) + SUM(M.Time_spent_h) AS Total_time
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Client_ID, Client, SUM(Time_spent_h) AS Time
    FROM
        table_1
    GROUP BY 1 , 2) AS M
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Client_ID, Client, SUM(Time_spent_h) AS Time
    FROM
        table_2
    GROUP BY 1 , 2) AS C ON C.ID = M.ID
GROUP BY 1 , 2
```

So far, this is the only way I have been able to join both tables, since `Client_ID` is the primary key in both datasets:

| Client_ID | Client | Total_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Levis | 26 |

I would like to get all the fields within both tables, but only the results that match on the same `Client` or `Client_ID`.

| Name | Team | Rol | Client | Service | Time spent (h) | Client ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Marketing | Analyst | Levis | Email | 5 | 001 |
| Max | Marketing | Manager | Levis | Paid Media | 7 | 001 |
| Noah | Business | Analyst | Levis | Operations | 8 | 001 |
| Alex | Business | KAM | Levis | Consultancy | 6 | 001 |

My final goal with this query is to return all the information related to both teams that have worked on the same clients, in this example is Levis but there are more clients. Can I get this using join or should I use something else?

Comment: What happened to Damien and Mary?

Comment: As they worked on different clients they were not included. In the expected output I want only those who have spent time in the same clients

Comment: What if, e.g., Anne worked with client #2? There would be two subgroups now. Can you enhance the dataset? As it is, is not clear enough to see edge cases.

Comment: Done, let me know if I made my idea cleaner, thanks!

Comment: so you want all the people who worked on a client id that appears in both tables?

Comment: Exactly, so far I have just been able to join both tables with the total time worked on the clients due to the ID, but also I need the rest of the fields from both tables. Since those fileds don't have an ID I dont know how to join that information in one single result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need to figure out which `Client_ID` values exist in both tables.  This is an intersect operation, but not all DBMSs have an intersect operator, so you can do it using an `exists` clause.

```
with
    clients as (
        select distinct client_id 
        from table1
        where exists (
            select 1 from table2
            where table2.client_id = table1.client_id
        )
    )
select * from table1 where client_id in (select client_id from clients)
union all
select * from table2 where client_id in (select client_id from clients)
```

Or if you do have an `intersect` available:

```
with
    clients as (
        select client_id from table1
        intersect
        select client_id from table2
    )
select * from table1 where client_id in (select client_id from clients)
union all
select * from table2 where client_id in (select client_id from clients)
```